# How to insert an attribute into xml data which is saved as nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say there is the following XML data and I want to add an attribute into salary like `currency="INR"`:

```
<employee>
    <salary amount="6000"/>
</employee>
```

1. If this data is stored in a column of type `XML`, then another attribute is being added easily just by using this code snippet:

   ```
   UPDATE TABLENAME 
   SET COLUMNNAME.modify('insert attribute currency{"INR"} into (/employee/salary)[1]')
   ```
2. and if this data is stored in a column of type `nvarchar(max)`, then the following query is not working even after casting the data as `xml`:

   ```
   UPDATE TABLENAME 
   SET CAST(CAST(COLUMNNAME AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML).modify('insert attribute currency{"INR"} into (/employee/salary)[1]')
   ```

So, help me to resolve second point as I have a column as nvarchar and I need to insert an attribute into saved xml data.

Comment: Yes - and is there a **question** in here somewhere!?!?!?

Comment: Hi marc_s, thanks for quickly looking into it. Now, I have updated my question.

Comment: I understand that it should be of XML type and definitely it will be changed to XML but if, it is about doing then found it as a challenge but could not understand the reason hence, posted it here and also to know how it will be resolved.

Comment: Yes, first one is working fine for me.

Comment: You know already, that the only answer can be *Change this to XML*. For the meanwhile the easiest might be a simple `REPLACE(COLUMNNAME, 'salary amount="','salary currency="INR" amount="')`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[`modify() Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)** works only with variable/column directly and can only used in the `SET` clause.

So, to solve this since you are storing your data as `NVARCHAR`, you have two choices:

1. Alter your table and add a new column with `XML` datatype, move the data to it from your column, and then `UPDATE` the data using `modify()`
2. Create/declare a table to store your data as `XML` and do the `UPDATE`.

Here is an example for what you provide:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
  Value NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO T
SELECT N'<employee>
           <salary amount="6000"/>
         </employee>';

DECLARE @V XML;

SELECT @V = CAST(Value AS XML)
FROM T;

SET @V.modify('insert attribute currency{"INR"} into (/employee/salary)[1]');

UPDATE T
SET Value = CAST(@V AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

SELECT * FROM T;
```

**[Live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ca21c4a1341ec19c710483c333a21be3)**